# How to run a workflow with parameters

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm new using Elsa and I try to run a hello world example.
When we need to call the workflow, we just need to call this sentence:

```
await runner.BuildAndStartWorkflowAsync<HelloWorld>()
```

I'm wondering for example how I can call the HelloWorld class but sending some parameters that are coming from outside.

BuildAndStartWorkflowAsync has some parameters, one of them is input of type WorkflowInput, which I assume is used to send values to the workflow. Once I call the workflow, it goes to the HelloWorld/Build method, how can I read this input from there?

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: from what I've found so far, anything you pass as a "WorkflowInput" will be available in the WorkflowExecutionContext.Input. I've got an instance of a WorkflowExecutionContext through the ActivityExecutionContext. 
In an Activity:

protected override IActivityExecutionResult OnExecute(ActivityExecutionContext context)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found that too, when you call BuildAndStartWorkflowAsync, there is a param named "input", I will edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of calling the workflow with initial parameters it is:

```
await runner.BuildAndStartWorkflowAsync<HelloWorld>(input: new WorkflowInput(yourobject));
```

where "yourobject" is whatever you want, a class for example with some properties.

Comment: Can you further elaborate how is the WorkflowInput parameter is accessible in Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)  function? I tried to explore some properties in IWorkflowBuilder  however could not locate how to access the input parameter passed while workflow being triggered.